# Java Spring uploaded image not showing in jsp

Tags: java, spring, image, hibernate, jsp

I have a strange problem showing a .jpg image in a .jsp page.
I´ve had lots of problems uploading an image to my resource folder, but finally I got it. The image uploads correctly both to the database and to the resource folders. 
I have a resource folder and inside it a folder to store all images.I also have a table on my db in which I save the name of the image, the id of the image and the id of the element that it belongs to.
When I load the .jsp of the gallery, I pass a list with the images and using a "for each", I show them on the .jsp.

This is the code of the jsp:

```
<c:set var="rutaImagen" value="${'img/maquinas/fullsize/'}"></c:set>
        <c:set var="rutaThumbnail" value="${'img/maquinas/thumbnails/'}"></c:set>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row no-gutter popup-gallery">
                <!-- Añadimos cada imagen del listado -->
                <c:forEach items="${listaImagenes }" var="imagen">
                    <c:set var="nombreImagenCompleto" value="${rutaImagen}${imagen.nombreImagen }"></c:set>
                    <c:set var="nombreThumbnailCompleto" value="${rutaThumbnail}${imagen.nombreImagen }"></c:set>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                        <a class="portfolio-box" href="${nombreImagenCompleto}">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="${nombreThumbnailCompleto}" alt="">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                        Ampliar                                         
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </a>
                        <div>                               
                            <input type="radio" name="imagenSeleccionada" id="${imagen.idImagen}" value="${imagen.idImagen}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>  

            </div>
```

This is an image showing ok:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                        <a class="portfolio-box" href="img/maquinas/fullsize/3.jpg">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/maquinas/thumbnails/3.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                        Ampliar                                         
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </a>
                        <div>                               
                            <input type="radio" name="imagenSeleccionada" id="3" value="3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

ANd this is an uploaded image not showing ok:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                        <a class="portfolio-box" href="img/maquinas/fullsize/DSCN1062.JPG">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/maquinas/thumbnails/DSCN1062.JPG" alt="">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                        Ampliar                                         
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </a>
                        <div>                               
                            <input type="radio" name="imagenSeleccionada" id="41" value="41">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

As you can see, the resulting path is the same, but one is ok and one isn´t.

I have seen something strange...The gallery page loads thumbnails,and when you clik on one of them, you can see the full picture. But I have seen that the thumbnail isn´t showing, but when you click on it, you can see the full picture ok.

Comment: The obvious question is: does `DSCN1062.JPG` actually exist in the path you are checking? And by that, I don't just mean that the image is there, but that your code is using the *exact* filename, even the case. i.e. Is the file name actually all uppercase?

Comment: Yes.The file was uploaded with this name is uppercase.The file exists in the specified location. When I upload a picture, I create the thumbnail with Thumbnailator and upload it to the thumbnails folder. The file is stored with the same name for the thumbnail and for the fullsize picture, then...why the fullsize works and the thumbnail doesn´t?

Comment: And the thumbnail generator doesn't change the case (even for .jpg) or append to the filename e.g. DSCN1062_thumb.JPG? Or adding a space somewhere in the filename by mistake? Sorry for the obvious questions, but there's no other obvious reasons and we can't see your files, 
so its hard to see what else could be causing the problem

Comment: Sorry, the thumbnail was been saved with a lowercase name.Now it is working ok.